# Updating 3 axes in a loop

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-guide, matlab-cvst

I have two webcams connected to my laptop. I am trying my hand at computer vision. I have created 3 axes on my GUI. I want to continuously update the axes with the data from webcams and its output. The first 2 axes display the webcam 1 and webcam 2 inputs. The 3rd axes displays the stereoAnaglyph. The 3rd axes needs some processing time, so I want to update the all the 3 axes to next data only after the 3rd axes is updated. How can I make the axes update continuously?

Comment: Did you already get the import from both webcams working?

Comment: Yes. I am able to get a continuous stream from the webcams.

Comment: The easiest trick I can think of would be to have a sampling frequency smaller than the calculation frequency (That you can approximate on the first run)

Comment: So... I set a timer which triggers the capture from webcam and depending on the calculation time?

Comment: I think you can specify a sampling rate on your webcam object can't you?

Comment: I am using videoinput function to get the feed from webcam and I use getsnapshot function to get an image from the webcam and pass it to other functions for processing. The documentation for videoinput does not say anything about sampling. Is there a better function i can use?